# Why is it useful to calculate the square root when performing Primality test?

Tags: prime-numbers, square-numbers

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Trial_division) (emphasis mine):

> The most basic method of checking the primality of a given integer n
>   is called trial division. This routine consists of dividing `n` by each
>   integer `m` that is greater than 1 and less than or equal **to the square
>   root** of `n`. If the result of any of these divisions is an integer, then
>   `n` is not a prime, otherwise it is a prime.

Why do we assume that if `n` is not a product of any number between 2 and `sqrt(n)` it is also not a product of any number higher than `sqrt(n)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n$ is not prime then $n=ab$ where both factors are less than $n$. They can't both be greater than $\sqrt{n}$, so in your search  if you get to $\sqrt{n}$ without finding a factor you'll never find one so can stop searching.

If you're interested in finding primes you might want to check out the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Answer (score 1):

If we have a factor $f>\sqrt{N}$ , then $$f':=\frac{N}{f}<\frac{N}{\sqrt{N}}= \sqrt{N}$$ is a factor as well , so we only need to check until the square root.